# Why Isn't My .Net Object Serializable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I've got a 'MyDataTable' class that inherits from System.Data.DataTable

I've implemented ISerializable in my class and have a 'Public Overrides Sub GetObjectData...'

But when I try to serialize the an object of 'MyDataTable' I get an error saying that 'MyDataTable' is not marked as serializable.

If I used a DataTable instead - my code serializes correctly.
If I add a serializable attribute to the 'MyDataTable' class - it serializes correctly, but I'm told that is unnecessary if I implement ISerializable.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whoever told you it is unnecessary to add the [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) is incorrect:

> Apply the SerializableAttribute attribute even if the class also implements the ISerializable interface to control the serialization process.

And from the [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) entry (**em** added):

> Any class that might be serialized **must be marked with the SerializableAttribute**. If a class needs to control its serialization process, it can implement the ISerializable interface.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  My testing seems to support that and examples I've found in the MSDN seem to agree as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the SerializableAttribute, even if you implement ISerializable. Although this discusses an FxCop rule, this is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182350(VS.80).aspx:

> To be recognized by the common
>   language runtime as serializable,
>   types must be marked with the
>   SerializableAttribute attribute even
>   if the type uses a custom
>   serialization routine through
>   implementation of the ISerializable
>   interface.