# When I change a value in one list of collection , another list that is a copy of first list, also changed

Tags: vb.net, collections

I'm writing a project in vb 2010
My problem is here:

```
    Dim s1 As New List(Of blocks)
    Dim s As New blocks
    s.Type = blocks.Khane_Type.Block
    s1.Add(s)
    s = New blocks
    s.Type = blocks.Khane_Type.Hadaf
    s1.Add(s)
    Dim s2 As List(Of blocks) = New List(Of blocks)
    s2 = s1.GetRange(0, 2)

    s1(0).Type = blocks.Khane_Type.Player

    MsgBox(s2(0).Type.ToString)
```

When I change a value in s1 list, s2 list also changed. Why?????? What is the problem?

Comment: Because it holds a reference to the first one

Comment: I don't want it to hold ref to the first one. How can I do?

Comment: Then make it it's own object `Dim s2 As New List(Of blocks)` not `s2 = s1.GetRange(0, 2)` how does that not make since? Then newly declared objects to it.

Answer (score 2):

s2 is a "shallow copy" of your list, which means is copying the pointer and not the object itself. If you want to copy the "content" of your object (rather than the pointer), you should make a **deep copy**. I have prepared this simple working example, hope it will helps to understand the concept and fix your code.

```
    Dim a As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    a.Add("ciao")
    a.Add("hi")
    a.Add("hallo")

    'shallow copy sc
    Dim sc As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    sc = a 'sc will store just the pointer of a. So, if a changes, sc changes as well since it still points to the object a.

    'deep copy dc
    Dim dc As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Using stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

        Dim formatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
        formatter.Serialize(stream, a)
        stream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        dc = formatter.Deserialize(stream) 'dc is storing the content of a in its own memory. It's a bit longer procedure because you need to create it a memory, but now even if a changes, dc will be the same.

    End Using

    a(1) = "goodbye"

    MsgBox("sc(1) changed to " & sc(1) & " while dc(1) is still " & dc(1))
```

So, following the example above, if you replace `s2 = s1.GetRange(0,2)` with the code below, you will see that s2 will not change together with s1 and you will be able to change s1 as you want without impacting s2:

```
Using stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

    Dim formatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
    formatter.Serialize(stream, s1)
    stream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    s2 = formatter.Deserialize(stream) 

End Using
```

Comment: I got this error:Type 'Chakosh.blocks' in Assembly 'Chakosh, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: This is because your object (I guess a custom class) is not serializable, as the error say. Use this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2961958/3111149) to add the serializable attribute to your class and the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The elements of s2 still point to the same underlying objects (it is a shallow copy).

I.e. s2 contains references to the same block object instances as the elements 0, 1 and 2 of s1

To make complete copies of your object depends on what your Block class is/does. You may find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx basic overview of the difference between a value type and a reference type useful.

If the Block class has only value type fields then a memberwise clone http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx is sufficient (this link also explains the key differences between a shallow and deep copy).

If it contains reference fields (e.g. references to other objects) you should add a .Copy or .Clone method. Essentially, such a method would create a new instance of its class, assigning its values to the new class value fields (or first doing a memberwise clone) and dealing with the reference types (how depends on what they are).

You should start a new question explaining your Block object and best practices for making copies of instances of it.

Comment: How can I fix it? I want s1 to be separated from s2.